# Image background in css

Tags: css

Is there a way to dynamically resize the image on the page background? I have a background that repeats on Y axes but if I make the height size bigger and if the page contains less content then the backgroun does not fit properly.. can anyone please help? thanks

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112597/stretch-image-as-background

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score -1):

Indeed what you want is not yet possible (perhaps in CSS3 ?). The best way to go as of yet I think is using the CSS background-attachment.

```
body {
 background-attachment: fixed; /*background doesn't scroll out of the screen */
 background-position: top center; /* background's center is in the center of the window */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are CSS3 descriptors that do this:

```
#my-id {background-size: 100% 100%;}
```

http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm

Hope this helps!